# .Net Application for Creating SP's in SQl

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a Dot net application and provide an environment to a user may be Multiline Text box, where user can Paste the predefined SP and Execute. After execution this Sp should be created in DB

Any ideas are invited..

Comment: Please expand on your requirements?  Also, have you considered the security implications of allowing stored procedures to be created on the fly by users?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do thid for a internal support application or something like that, not to the end-user, right?

Anyway, you need to be more specific, but the way you would create a procedure doesnt differ the way you would run a insert statment for example.

Simple example:

```
SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(your_connection_string);
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(tbProcedureCode.text, objConnection);
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

objConnection.Open();
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Our requirement is something like, SP code will be given by Users. Same SP we just execute in DB to create or Alter. We also dont understand the logic in the SP. We will provide security as required. I shall try the one you suggested and come back... Thanks.